# WP Rest API - filter by format (request with a filter)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm send reguest to WP Rest API like

```
my.site/restapi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=4
```

How I can get posts only with **format** value **aside**?

I heard that сlosing as filter has been removed in 4.7. What are the ways to solve this issue? How can I send a request with a filter today?

Comment: Check out this github repo: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2683 This may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, as of 4.7 the filter has been removed, you need to replace it with the simple plugin https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter

Comment: And then the syntax change slightly https://www.mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=sport